# DRV8711 SPI mode

Tags: avr, spi, stepper-motor, texas-instruments, xmega

I'm facing some problems with SPI bus of DRV8711 (http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8711.pdf). Repetitive reads of the same register give the same values but the communication doesn't seem reliable.

I'm using two BOOST-DRV8711 dev boards (http://www.ti.com/tool/boost-drv8711) connected on the same SPI of an xmega, with different SS pins, of course. Currently I connected on ly the following pins:

- motor power supply (12V)
- SPI bus (SCK, MISO, MOSI, SS)
- RESET and SLEEP

The SPI bus frequency is set at 250 kHz and the edges of the signals are good.
First question: I'm not sure about the SPI mode to use. Here the common examples of the four modes:

[image: SPI modes]

and this is diagram at page 26 of the datasheet:

[image: DRV8711 SPI diagram]

I understand the DRV8711 samples on the rising edge of the provided clock signal which leads to SPI modes 0 or 3.
In mode 0 the rising edge is also the first edge of the clock, while in mode 3 the rising edge is the second and last edge.

I don't understand if the numbers placed on that edges represent the samples point or the clock's cycles.

Of course I've already tried both modes but none is working perfectly. In mode 0 it seems I can read correctly, but the DRV8711 doesn't always understand the writings.

And the most weird behavior is both modules receive the same commands (i.e. microstepping) even if only the related SS pin is triggered:

```
DRV8711_WakeUp();
DRV8711_Reset();
DRV8711_SetMode(&PORTA, PIN4_bm, DRV8711_REG_CTRL_MODE_128);
DRV8711_SetMode(&PORTA, PIN3_bm, DRV8711_REG_CTRL_MODE_2);
DRV8711_SetEnable(&PORTA, PIN4_bm, true);
DRV8711_SetEnable(&PORTA, PIN3_bm, true);
```

Well, both drivers are set with mode 128 or 2 (across different runs).
I bet the SPI communication is not reliable due to wrong settings.

Comment: Are you sure you are reading the *correct* register on reads? You simply say you get the same thing from a given register.

Comment: Yes, I've just _corrected_ the question. I only read the same thing from a given register. After a reset, some registers have their default value as indicated in the ds, other don't have.

Comment: Found. The SDO line from DRV8711 is open-drain. I enabled the internal pull-up of the MCU but it wasn't enough. I had to put a (stronger) external pull-up.